# Weight in Vertical Linear Layout

Tags: android

I m confused about weight in vertical linear layout. I can use the weight well in horizontal linear layout but how to use it in vertical linear layout. I have a relative layout which contains a liner layout(vertical) that has some text-view and text-fields.I want the following arrangement.
[image]

Red line=relative layout,Green Line=Linear Layout(vertical),blue=textview,yellow=texfields

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what you have tried add your code which you develop.

Comment: in your vertical linear layout set height as match_parent and set weight of each text_view as 1

Comment: I tried with 1 textview and 1 texdfields which works well with horizontal linear layout but if I use more views what to do?

Comment: I'd recommend using a `TableLayout` for this. If I've got this right, you're trying to apply weighting horizontally so you have regular columns in your `LinearLayout`. Assuming that's right, then you'll never do it like this.

`LinearLayout` arranges all elements either horizontally or vertically within itself. It can't do it both ways. So you'd need a separate row container in any case to achieve your goal.

`TableLayout` is not only designed with that intrinsic row container, but also has built in column support for just this sort of layout without requiring weighting to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />


    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />


    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanx Mukesh bhai, this is WHAT I myself guessed. Why doesnt the developer guide clearly state that "weight" works ONLY with the horizontal linear layout. Whatever u want to put with weight that has to be in horizontal linear layout.

Comment: Weight works with both vertical and horizontal layouts. I've used it with both successfully.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the layout_weigth parameter, you should have parameter related to the orientation of the linear layout on match_parent

so:

```
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: whats the difference between match parent and fill parent ? and should I use the above on views or layout? bcos I read that the width of the views shud be set to 0dp while using weight.

Comment: match_parent and fill_parent are the same. Yes, try match_parent on the textview's

Comment: How do I implement an arrangement in a vertical linear layout with the help of weight(1:2 for 2 views) in a 2x3 table like form.

Comment: how can I use match_parent on the textview's since I m using weight for that view,...the width of the views shud be set to 0dp while using weight

Answer (score 1):

**-** First of all you can **directly** have that arrangement in the `Relative layout` **without** the use of `LinearLayout`.

**-** Secondly if you want to have a child layout in the `Relative layout`, then its better to use `TableRow` in your `Relative layout`, and arrange the elements in it, just as u have shown.

Comment: I know I can but I just want to know if I can do this otherway, just to learn..How do I implement an arrangement in a vertical linear layout with the help of weight(1:2 for 2 views) in a 2x3 table like form

Comment: NOW I think I can only use weight in horizontal liner layout, NOT IN vertical linear layout..

Comment: A `TableLayout` would be my recommended layout type for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a `TableLayout` for this. If I've got this right, you're trying to apply weighting horizontally so you have regular columns in your `LinearLayout`. Assuming that's right, then you'll never do it like this.

`LinearLayout` arranges all elements either horizontally or vertically within itself. It can't do it both ways. So you'd need a separate row container in any case to achieve your goal.

`TableLayout` is not only designed with that intrinsic row container, but also has built in column support for just this sort of layout without requiring weighting to manage.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , after alittle games with vertical weight issue , i understood that android will
wrap around the content of a ViewGroup and even if you set it with a weight that is bigger from the size of its content it will wrap around the content and give the extra space to the other views.

**The solution is to add margin Top or Bottom depend on your needs .**